# GitLab UI not opening up

Tags: postgresql, docker, redis, kubernetes, gitlab

I am running separate GitLab, Redis and PostgreSQL containers in Kubernetes with GlusterFS for persistence. All Kubernetes nodes are having RancherOS. All nodes have 1 core and 4.5 GB RAM. Docker version on all nodes is `1.12.6` to ensure compatibility with Kubernetes.

GitLab service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: gitlab
  name: gitlab
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "443"
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: "10022"
    port: 10022
    targetPort: 22
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: gitlab
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

When i start GitLab container in Kubernetes, [here](https://pastebin.com/nXF45Scf) is the log. I am able to telnet to the *host* on port 80 where the GitLab pod is running but somehow the GitLab page is not opening up. I get the following error when i hit the public URL (http://35.xxx.yyy.zz/):

```
 Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

I was trying to investigate using some commands described in [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23088) page but rake command is failing.

```
root@gitlab-748072774-chztb:/home/git/gitlab# rake
rake     rake2.3
root@gitlab-748072774-chztb:/home/git/gitlab# which rake2.3
/usr/bin/rake2.3
root@gitlab-748072774-chztb:/home/git/gitlab# rake gitlab:check
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /usr/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
root@gitlab-748072774-chztb:/home/git/gitlab# rake2.3 gitlab:check
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /usr/bin/rake2.3:22:in `<main>'
```

Any pointers?

Comment: _`# which rake2.3`_ did you observe on the troubleshooting page you linked to that the command is actually `gitlab-rake`?

Comment: _ telnet to the host on port 80 where the GitLab pod is running_ I hope you mean "I used curl" and not literally telnet, otherwise you will need to type the http protocol by hand. And when you say "to the host on port 80" do you mean the Pod's IP, the Service IP, the Node's IP, other?

Comment: `status: loadBalancer: {}` we will need the output of `kubectl get -o yaml svc gitlab` in order to understand if there is an assigned `LoadBalancer` to that Service (but either way, I would for sure expect `curl` on the Pod itself to help troubleshoot the situation)

Comment: 1) Yes, i did see on the link that it was `gitlab-rake` but that command wasn't there inside the GitLab pod. `rake` was there because i am using [this](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#rake-tasks) image. 2) I literally used `telnet` to the host's IP (Public IP provided by Google Cloud) where the pod was running. Like in Docker, when we use `-p` to publish port, what's the equivalent in Kubernetes? Is it `targetPort`?

Comment: _ I literally used telnet to the host's IP where the pod was running_ well, then you'll need `curl` or `printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' | telnet $the_ip 80` because just telnet-ing to the port is the webserver waiting patiently for a legal http request

Comment: _Like in Docker, when we use -p to publish port, what's the equivalent in Kubernetes_ I'd have to dig up your other post containing the Pod descriptor, but in the Pod spec is [container: ports:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#containerport-v1-core) where you tell k8s ports that _can be targeted_ by `targetPort`

Comment: _because i am using this image_ is there a great reason why you do not want to use [the official ones](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/)?

Comment: 1) `curl http://IP` gives the same error message that i mentioned in my post when hitting the URL. Here IP that i used is that of the host where pod is running. How do i get GitLab's pod IP? If i do `docker inspect f43c57660cbc | grep -i ip`, i don't see any IP assigned in the output returned by the command. 2) Output of `kubectl get -o yaml svc gitlab` is [here](https://pastebin.com/nXF45Scf) 3) I'm using official image of PostgreSQL and his Redis & GitLab images. I'm learning. Once i'm more confident, i will try all the official ones.

Comment: _How do i get GitLab's pod IP_ `kubectl get -o yaml pod $the_pod_name` (it will be in the `status: podIP:` key); and if there is no IP returned from `docker inspect`, then you have a software-defined network, meaning the Pod's IP exists only in the imagination of the cluster

Comment: From the command `kubectl get -o yaml pod $the_pod_name`, i do see podIP but that's an internal one `10.42.208.206`. From my laptop, it wouldn't work as these are on Google Cloud. Yes, `docker inspect` doesn't return any IP.

Comment: BTW, at this point your posts are treating StackOverflow like a forum, where it is less "what is the command for ..." and more "I have this problem, and then this problem, and ..." so you may find the [kubernetes slack channel](http://slack.k8s.io/) to be more interactive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154008/discussion-between-matthew-l-daniel-and-technext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 93 of https://pastebin.com/nXF45Scf shows what's going on:

> `type: ClusterIP`

Means that Service, and its in-cluster IP address, are only available to other members of the cluster. If you were expecting it to show up on any kind of public IP, you would want [type: LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#servicespec-v1-core)
 as described [in the concepts document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types)

Comment: My test environment is on Google Cloud but the actual implementation will happen on VM instances running in private data center. In that case, i will have to install a separate LoadBalancer container, correct? On host setup is anyways not possible as i'm using RancherOS which only allows container to run.

Comment: _In that case, i will have to install a separate LoadBalancer container, correct_ correct, and they are called [Ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) of which there are about 5 currently, and yes, they run fine in containers, as you can (and often do) run them from within the cluster itself

Comment: _on VM instances running in private data center_ given that, you may be happier running one of the many VirtualBox based clusters on your machine, as it will most closely resemble the for-real environment; it sounds like you are battling Google Cloud, but those scars will not pay of in the long run